# Compile Error QT - cannot cast from type

Tags: c++, linux, macos, qt, gcc

I tryed to compile a project on QT, but shows many errors, one of them at this second line:

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(...
printf("save clustering: %s\n",filename.toStdString() ); // ERROR
```

> ... error: cannot cast from type 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >') to pointer type 'char *'
>            printf("save clustering: %s\n",filename.toStdString() );

This project was builded on Linux (gcc 5.2.1) but i transferred to a Mac OS X Sierra (gcc 5.4.0). I dont know what i can do to solve the problem. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You might need to call the `c_str()` function of that string. However, why are you using `printf()` instead of `std::cout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` can't handle `std::string` as a parameter, instead you have to choose one of these:

```
filename.toLocal8Bit.data()
filename.toLatin1().data()
filename.toStdString().c_str()
filename.toStdWString().c_str()
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Qt,

you can use `QDebug` to print in console.

***It won't require any conversions.***

You can print `QString` directly.

```
qDebug() << filename;
```

***Note***: you may require to include `#include <qdebug.h>`